Homeomorphism between a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I consider the set, for $\varepsilon>0$ fixed :
$$
E=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 :x\in\mathbb{R},z\in\mathbb{R}, \exists d\in(0,\varepsilon), y= d-z\}
$$
We first observe that we have two free variables, let’s say it is $x$ and $z$. From this observation and some (misleading maybe) drawing, I would like to prove that the set is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Seeking for an homeomorphism encoding all the information, I first thought to try $f(x,y,z)=(x,d)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\varepsilon)$. However this is clearly not injective.
Thus I tried to exploit the free variable and looked at $f(x,y,z)=(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ however this does not work, especially because $d$ varies on $(0,\varepsilon)$.
The case where $d$ is fixed is easier, but I do not see how to recover the set $E$ starting from this.
If you have some hints to provide, I would be happy to learn it !
Thank you a lot

The reason you're hitting a snag is they aren't homeomorphic.

Thank you for this remark, if you refer to my title it was not correct I modified it !

$E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So it cannot be homeomorphic to (an open subset of) $\mathbb{R}^2$.

@freakish Did not think to this.. thank you a lot !

Your set builder notation has some flaws which, perhaps, lead to the confusions you are experiencing. Namely, the variables $\epsilon$ and $d$ have not been quantified in any way. And this ambiguity is reflected in your post: the "two cases", depending on whether or not $d$ is fixed, should be clarified in the problem statement. I suspect that the original intention is something like this: Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $$E = {(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb R,  \exists d \in (0,\epsilon), y = d - z}$$ This not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, as said by @freakish.

Another possibility is this: Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $d \in (0,\epsilon)$, let $$E = {(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb R, y = d-z}$$ However, in this formulation the epsilon is redundant, you could have just written Given $d>0$ let... and the set $E$ would be unchanged.

@LeeMosher You are totally right ! Sorry for this, I was lazy. I updated the post, and with the quantifiers appearing clearly we can check that the set is open and conclude as one comment noticed !

I think it should be pretty easy to write down a homeomorphism between your set $E$ and $\Bbb R^2×(0,\epsilon),$ which is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2.$
